# How to turn on optimization in C source code?

Tags: c, optimization, gcc

Is it possible to write C code so that when it is compiled with

```
gcc -o foo foo.c
```

it in fact compiles foo.c with -O2?

I am using gcc 4.4.6.

Comment: Are you doing the optimization lab from  Bryant and O'Hallaron CS:APP?

Comment: `alias gcc='gcc -O2'`

Comment: @MarcB I need it in the C source itself.

Comment: @ScottyBauer I am setting work and want to know if they can trick me easily!

Comment: wrt "I need it in the C source": you can rebuild `gcc` to change this behavior.  [Beware, consumers of @marshall's new compiler](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/ken/trust.html)!

Comment: Won't that make your debugging more difficult?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

recent gcc knows a `#pragma GCC optimize` pragma (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html)